# How to only display variables in thymeleaf which ain't null

Tags: java, spring, attributes, thymeleaf

I've got a List with image url's and I only want to display the one's that are not null. But i've tried many things and nothing seems to work.

This is the HTML code:

```
 <ul class="first">
 <div th:each="image : ${car.getImageUrl()}">
     <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <a th:href="${image}" class="pop" data-id="${image}">
            <img class="img-responsive thumbnailsmaller" th:src="${image}"/>
        </a>
     </li>
 </div>         
</ul>
```

And this is the output:

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `th:if` like this:

```
<ul class="first">
 <div th:each="image : ${car.getImageUrl()}" th:if="${!#strings.isEmpty(image)}">
     <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <a th:href="${image}" class="pop" data-id="${image}">
            <img class="img-responsive thumbnailsmaller" th:src="${image}"/>
        </a>
     </li>
 </div>         
</ul>
```

Also, make sure your image urls are valid, test them with chrome developer tools and see if there is no url for those images, because your urls may also be broken because of a reason.

Comment: Thanks but it isn't working because the first 4 items aren't null.

Comment: What do you mean by first 4 items aren't null? You got nothing when you try this? Also in the screenshot you got three items not null?

Comment: I mean the getImageUrl returns an arraylist so it isn't null, but there are 6 values which are null because they've no entry in the db. Only the first 3/4 items are filled by this car.

Comment: How about this? Sorry I just meant image, not car.getImageUrl()

Comment: I just updated solution as ${image != null && image != ""} could you please try again?

Comment: Yeah added #strings.isEmpty , could you please check if working?

Comment: Maybe a very dumb question but how do I do that. Im new to the community so I dont know everything now